# Configuring Kafka consumer in Spring Boot = loss control over consumer behavior?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, apache-kafka

I really like using all the configurations available in Spring Boot to configure Kafka consumers:

```
ConsumerFactory() => KafkaListenerContainerFactory() => consume(V message)
```

However, it seems that I am also losing all the control over the consumer behavior that comes with apache kafka package, like switching back and forth between sync and async commits, explicitly starting the consumer and cleanly shutting it down. 
With the Spring kafka interface, you only need to implement one method and you just start to get messages flowing in:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topics}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void consumeString(String message) {
    System.out.println("Consumed message: " + message);
}
```

It seems to me that all this consumption is taking place on a separate thread that Spring Boot provides automatically...
Can someone tell me how I can still keep all that control while using Spring Boot to configure KafkaConsumers (and by the same token KafkaProducers)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that all this consumption is taking place on a separate thread that Spring Boot provides automatically

That's correct, spring wraps the kafka consumer in listener container.

At most you can configure the behaviour thru [container properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html).

Theoretically, you could keep the most recent value returned by [kafka consumer factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/ConsumerFactory.html), but you need to keep in mind that for a single container it's possible to create a consumer multiple times. Anyways, with keeping the reference, you could get access to underlying kafka consumer *without* reflection. But that's a hack, and potentially you could impact behaviour of the container.

Comment: Thanks @Adam! What bothers me most is that if I follow the convention in Spring Boot, I don't get to control the start and (cleanly) shut down the consumer. Like you said, it's more like a hack if I really want to force it. Creating and configuring a KafkaConsumer without the help of Spring Boot is not too much trouble, so I am not quite seeing the major benefits...